# [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed.
Everything was running fine unless my Wifi got disconnected.
My desktop application was unable to find the sql server and was throwing the error message "[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied."

My application and the sql server is in the same machine.
I have my my protocols enabled and also I have disabled my firewall.
I am wondering why the sql server is unreachable when wifi gets turned off?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/91d479ce-284e-41af-bb43-9f5e1d3bb119/dbnetlibconnectionopen-connectsql-server-does-not-exist-or-access-denied?forum=sqldataaccess)

> > I went into the surface area configuration and set the remote connections to both TCP/IP and Named Pipes and restarted the server.